# Modelling async data in angularJS with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I am developing a single page app with angularJS and having an issue with storing async data.

To keep it simple, I basically have a service that holds some of my data models which are returned as promises (since they can be updating asynchronously at any given time).

I have an angular watch that updates these models when a certain condition changes.
I also have an angular watch that uses this data when certain conditions change.

My issue is this:
The watch that uses the data is firing before the watch that updates this data, causing it to fire immediately with the "stale" data instead of with the new promise.

Code Example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope, $q, asyncDataService) {

    // This watch is called whenever we need to update the asyncData
    $scope.$watch('variableThatCausesUpdate', function(newValue) {

        // Set the async data to a new unresolved promise to reflect
        // its pending nature
        var newAsyncDataDeferred = $q.defer();
        asyncDataService.setAsyncData(newAsyncDataDeferred.promise);

        // fetch the async data (in my case it is an $http request. 
        // newAsyncDataPromise is the $http promise)
        var newAsyncDataPromise = fetchAsyncData();

        // resolve the newData promise with the result from this fetch
        newAsyncDataPromise.then(function(newAsyncDataResult) {
            // At this point the data is up to date
            newAsyncDataDeferred.resolve(newAsyncDataResult.data);
        });

    });

    // This watch is called to perform some action, 
    // but is watching the same variable as update
    $scope.$watchCollection('[variableThatCausesUpdate, someOtherVariable]', function(newValue) {

        // We want to ensure that our asyncData is up to date, 
        // since we will be using it in our action
        asyncDataService.getAsyncData().then(function(asyncData) {
            // Firing with the "stale" promise since it occurs before update
            someActionRequiringOurAsyncData(asyncData);
        })

        /*
            However I can fix the issue by doing this 
            (since it will be put at the end of the event queue)
            But this seems ugly and maybe is the result of a bad design?
            setTimeout(function() {
                asyncDataService.getAsyncData().then(function(asyncData) {
                    someActionRequiringOurAsyncData(asyncData);
                })
            }, 0)

        */
    });

});
```

I can fix this issue by using a setTimeout 0 before calling the promise to ensure that the update happens first, but this feels gross and I'm starting to feel like I'm approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Of course I could just request the data whenever I need it, but this would lead to an enormous number of extraneous requests.

I can't just watch the result of the resolved promise, as other variables can trigger this watch as well so it is not only firing when that particular data is updated.

Comment: first, don't use `setTimeout` in Angular, use `$timeout` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

second, can you fire the second watch in the callback after the first promise resolves?

Comment: this timeout won't make sure, that your data is up-to-date. While you'r testing this on your local maschine, this will work...but in an real enviroment with 100-200ms response times.
Your architecture is smelly.

Comment: I'm using setTimeout because I don't want to fire unnecessary digest cycles. Is there any reason to use $timeout other than triggering a digest?

Also, why won't the timeout work in ensuring the data is up to date? The update and action requiring the update are always fired in the same digest cycle, so it just moves one of them to the end of the event loop. Once the update is called the promise is now unresolved, and it will wait correctly for it to finish. It doesn't rely on the actual duration of the timeout. Maybe I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the first watcher completely since you got the same var in the collection below.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope, $q, asyncDataService) {

    // This watch is called to perform some action, 
    // but is watching the same variable as update
    $scope.$watchCollection('[variableThatCausesUpdate, someOtherVariable]', function(newValue) {


        // We want to ensure that our asyncData is up to date, 
        // since we will be using it in our action
        asyncDataService.fetchAsyncData().then(function(asyncData) {
            // Firing with the "stale" promise since it occurs before update
            someActionRequiringOurAsyncData(asyncData);
        })  

    });

});
```

Comment: This would solve the issue of having to use a timeout, but would mean that I am making a new ajax request every time I need to use the variable (it is used very frequently and only updated occasionally). I want to have it cached locally since it only updates occasionally. 

Currently it is stored as a resolved promise until it needs to update, is an unresolved promise while updating, and then a resolved promise again when it finishes.

Maybe I should just set up caching? That could cause issues though because the same request may not always have the same response.